# How to use Post method without a Form

Tags: php, post, get

I am that kind that spends more time looking for bugs in web projects and correct them, but I still have one question about the use of the GET and POST method

To summarize , I often use the GET method for queries that may be coming from links or simple buttons example :

```
<a href="example.php?n=2030004">Click me</a>
```

and for forms (signup,login, or comment) I use the post method. but the question is:

sometimes (Multi-steps signup for e.g), I may need to pass the info collected from the form in page 1 to a page 2 (where the user can find a captcha for e.g). in order to send them to the database if the captcha test is Okey. But the question is , how to pass those info to a next page via a POST method without using a hidden form?
Do I need to recreate a POST method from scratch with a socket?

thank you

Comment: I am sorry , I just found a similar subject in another page but I think it's really a great subject to be duplicate.

Comment: with or without jquery/javascript??

Comment: No it's only about XTML an PHP. When some POST param passed to a 2nd page, I want to resend those info to a 3rd page without using a hidden form in the 2nd page (all this with post method)

Comment: Oliver is correct below. There probably isn't a much better solution (if I am understanding correctly) than using a session or cookie to store the data. In any case, you need to store that data somewhere. Depending on your motives, another potential solution would be to simply store the information to the database as you go. Then run a cron to check status and if older than a day or so purge results which are incomplete. But again, to keep things organized you would probably need a recurring post and/or session and error checking as these things can be spoofed in any case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use JavaScript ([jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)):

First u need to load jQuery ( using google as host or you download it):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

Then...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#Link').click(function() {
              $.post("example.php", { n: "203000"} );
         });
    });
    </script>

<a id="Link" href="#">Click me</a>
```

**Edit**:

after that save it in the [SESSION](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) in example.php

```
$ _SESSION['N'] = (int) $_POST['n'];
```

When this value will be stored on the server side. And tied to the client session, until he closes browser or that it set the time for that session on the server side runs out.

**Edit2**:
There is also another possibility to post requst, yes ..
But I do not like this method myself ...
And here is the form used, something the OP did not want.

```
<form name="myform" action="example.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="n" value="203000">
       <a id="Link" onclick="document.myform.submit()" href="#">Click me</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use sessions to store the data until you submit them:
http://de.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php.
Using sessions has a big advantage,
once you have verified the data you can store it.

Always keep in mind that users may manipulate POST requests!

Comment: @Ash care to follow the link?

Comment: I use session only in login,votes or views number (votes to prevent someone to vote twice , views to prevent incrementing the same user view twice..) but not in something that I can do with javascript. +1 anyhow

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is to pass info between pages like in a multi-step form you should use session (if you are using PHP).
By the way for send a POST request without form you need to use CURL like in this [example](http://php.dzone.com/news/execute-http-post-using-php-cu)

Comment: What's the use of curl in **this particular example** with multi-steps signup? where you going to send your data?

Answer (score 1):

The  statement is a HTML language statement used by a browser to initiate a POST/GET data relation. The Browser is the execution environment.

You can use other languages (and their execution environment) like Java, Java Script, C#, etc. to initiate HTTP POST/GET data relations.

Comment: Thank you +1, the question is 9 years old . You just triggered some memories from when I was 20. Best

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm not understanding you correctly, but from what I'm reading, you want to access form data entered on page 1 (using a form with a post method) on page 2? If so, use the $_POST autoglobal array. For example, $nameOnPage2 = $_POST['nameFromPage1']. You don't have to create a form on the second page for this.

Comment: no, the question is how to pass the info from the 2nd page to a 3rd page using the POST method without using a hidden form?

Comment: @Simo you desperatiely need to understand what the page is and where you want to send your data. Unless it would be completely waste of time.

Comment: the $_POST autoglobal array data from the page 1 just doesn't exist on the page 2. Go figure